# How can we access a specific element from a column in all records?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a feature named "Address" which has 65000 records. Each row has data, for example:

```
5-54,8th block,Koramangala,Bengaluru
```

I want to access only 'Koramangala'.
How can I do this?

Comment: All code, data, and error messages must be embedded as text, not images. Images cannot be copy-pasted into code editors or search engines. Text in images can also be difficult to read, especially on mobile devices.  Where is your coding attempt? This is not a fee code writing service, it's a platform to help each other resolve specific coding issues, like error messages or bugs. This question also likely already has an Answer to a very similar problem - try the SO search feature. SO quality and usefulness depends on it being used as designed. You can edit to bring this Q up to SO guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with select last but one value by indexing `[-2]`:

```
df['new'] = df['Address'].str.split(',').str[-2]
```